# Obtain null values of result from a query

Tags: sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT U.LOCATION,SUM(S.EXISTENCIA) AS Total
FROM LOCATIONS U
LEFT JOIN CANT_WAREHOUSE S ON U.LOCATION= S.LOCATION
WHERE U.ENABLED= 1 
GROUP BY U.LOCATION
```

And return data like this:

```
LOCATION  | Total
2A-1      | 566.0000000
2A-2      | 14.0000000
2A-3      | 1.0000000
2A-4      | (null)
2A-5      | 1.0000000
2A-6      | (null)
2A-7      | 6.0000000
2B-1      | 560.0000000
2B-2      | (null)
```

Is there a way to get the 'LOCATION' with 'TOTAL' = null using subquery or something like that?

Comment: `WHERE U.ENABLED = 1 AND S.LOCATION IS NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `HAVING` Clause

```
SELECT U.LOCATION,SUM(S.EXISTENCIA) AS Total 
FROM LOCATIONS U
LEFT JOIN CANT_WAREHOUSE S ON U.LOCATION= S.LOCATION
  and U.ENABLED= 1 
GROUP BY U.LOCATION
HAVING SUM(S.EXISTENCIA) IS NULL
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT U.LOCATION,
       NULL AS Total
FROM   LOCATIONS U
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   CANT_WAREHOUSE S
                   WHERE  U.LOCATION = S.LOCATION)
       AND U.ENABLED = 1
GROUP  BY U.LOCATION
```